# Schedule background task running every n minutes for ever in iOS apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process

I am trying to get the location updates in iOS application and also want to save it every 15 mins no matter application is in foreground or background. So definitely the `AppDelegate` is the class where I need to configure these.

I read about the background tasks, but it wasn't giving proper idea of the process. Can someone provide me with good source or link?

Comment: check this [background-location](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/)

Comment: Actually I now how to get the coordinates but my main concern is that how to run it in background continously irrespective of applications status i.e foreground or background state that is my main issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must check location at least every 3 minutes and create a backgroundTask using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`
more info in [here](http://hayageek.com/ios-long-running-background-task/)